# Why Fluent Migrator is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, migration, environment-variables, fluent-migrator

I am trying to run migrations with fluent migrator, I have this code that I put in the Package Manager console in Visual Studio:

```
..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.2\tools\Migrate.exe --conn  "DataSource=DESKTOP-8CSIJXV\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=No;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User ID=userName;Password=password" --provider SqlServer --assembly bin\debug\Migrations.dll.
```

When I run that code I get the error:

> ..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.2\tools\Migrate.exe :
>   The term '..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.2\tools\Migrate.exe'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + ..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.2\tools\Migrate.exe --conn "Data Sourc ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (..\packages\Flu...ols\Migrate.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + F

I already added `Migration.exe` as a path in the environment variables, but maybe I did something wrong because it is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running from an external command prompt?

Comment: It works!!!, thanks, I didn't know there was a difference, could you please create a nice answer more complete, including what's the different between command prompt and package manager console. So I can Vote yor answer as correct. Thanks again. @MarcL.

Comment: I'm looking into that... what you're trying still may be possible, but with a different path or syntax.  I'm not all that fluent in Powershell, but running an `exe` should be possible.  In Package Manager Console, did you try `dir` to check your location, see if your path to migrate.exe was correct?